# Android Clean all notifications when app crashes

Tags: android

I have an application which due to many reasons may crash. What I want is that when the application crashes it should remove all related notifications:

```
public class CrashHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    public CrashHandler(Context context) {
        this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            try {
                notificationManager.cancelAll();

            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        notificationManager = null;
        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
    }
}
```

and in my main Activity I called the above class:

```
new CrashHandler(context);
```

but when i run the application and the app crashes the notifications are not removed! any idea?

Comment: instead of resigning yourself to the crash, you shoud look **why** it crashs. If an app crash, in most cases you will have no chance to execute a method. If it crashs, it´s finished abruptly. I read some stuff about, that you can do some tricks by registering a service and execute the method in the service onDestroy(). But if that really helps, I have never tested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` in your application class like below.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Set your custom UncaughtExceptionHandler
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CrashHandler());

        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

In your AndroidMenifest.xml file set your Application class in name attribute.

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
```

After that when your app will crash due to uncaught exception,  `uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)` method will be called of your `CrashHandler` class before app crashed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I check it and let you know